# pyxmpp2 connect to openfire cannot resolve NXDOMAIN

Tags: python, xmpp, pyxmpp2

I installed pyxmpp2 `https://github.com/Jajcus/pyxmpp2`to my Ubuntu machine. I also installed Openfire 3.8.1 to it. I would like to use pyxmpp2 to connect to my Openfire server within the same machine.

In the Server -> Server Manager-> Server Information in my Openfire control panel, the Server Name showed in Server Properties in the panel was mymachine and the Host Name showed in the Environment section was MyMachine.

I tried the following code:

```
import logging
from pyxmpp2.jid import JID
from pyxmpp2.client import Client
logging.basicConfig()
client = Client(JID("admin@mymachine"),[])
client.connect()
```

and got the following message:

WARNING:pyxmpp2.resolver:Could not resolve '_xmpp-client._tcp.mymachine': NXDOMAIN

Did I miss configuring something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are no DNS SRV records for your domain and pyxmpp2 is therefore unable to resolve them. Have a look at http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records on how to create them.

Basically a DNS SRV record has the form

> _service._proto.name TTL class SRV priority weight port target

which could look like this example

```
_xmpp-client._tcp.example.net. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 5222 example.net.
```

Maybe pyxmpp2 also provides a way to directly specify the host used for the XMPP service. This would avoid the DNS SRV lookup.

Comment: DNS SRV records are not required by the XMPP protocol, but are encouraged. The server section in your JID "admin@mymachine" (so, mymachine) has to resolve for the python library. Try "nslookup mymachine" or "dig mymachine" to troubleshoot. Use the EXACT SAME SERVER NAME as what you have in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the link `http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records` but I do not find out how to create the SRV record. Could you give me more detailed instruction? Do I need to install "bind"?

Answer (score 0):

It may be using ipv6, you can force ipv4 using `u"ipv4": True` and specifing the server `u"server": "chat.facebook.com"`

```
handler = MyHandler(JID(target_jid), message)
settings = XMPPSettings({
                            u"ipv4": True,
                            u"server": "chat.facebook.com",
                            u"password": your_password,
                            u"starttls": True,
                            u"tls_verify_peer": False,
                        })
client = Client(JID(your_jid), [handler], settings)
client.connect()
client.run()
```

The full code is located on the `pyxmpp2` examples folder `send_message_client.py`